# C++ Stringbuilder insert, reverse and rearrange multiple strings

Tags: string, c++-cli, stringbuilder

I learned of Stringbuilder today and have been messing around with it as it might be the easiest or fastest method to do what I need to do.

I have a text file such as this:

```
Zach LCPL Schytt
Bill CPL John
Mark LCPL Simmons
...etc
```

I use the function below to read it from a listbox to a textbox.

```
StringBuilder^ sb = gcnew StringBuilder();
        Convertor^ form2 = gcnew Convertor();
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1->Items->Count; i++){
                String^ temp = listBox1->Items[i]->ToString();
                sb->AppendFormat("{0}", temp)->AppendLine();
            }
            form2->textBox1->Text = sb->ToString();
            form2->ShowDialog();
```

How do I go about making it look like the following instead? For each name,

```
dn: CN=Schytt LCPL Zach,DC=Sample,DC=Site
changetype: add
displayName: Schytt.Zach
```

I looked into `insert`, and stuff but don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
StringBuilder^ sb = gcnew StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1->Items->Count; i++)
{
    String^ temp = listBox1->Items[i]->ToString();

    // First, separate the input string.
    array<String^>^ strings = temp->Split();
    String^ firstName = strings[0];
    String^ rank = strings[1];
    String^ lastName = strings[2];

    // Then build the output string. (Remember that the C++ compiler 
    // concatenates strings at compile time, so we don't need a plus sign.)
    sb->AppendFormat("dn: CN = {2} {3} {1},DC=Sample,DC=Site{0}"
                     "changetype: add{0}"
                     "displayName: {2}.{1}{0}", 
                     Environment::Newline, //0
                     firstName, //1
                     lastName, //2
                     rank); //3
}

form2->textBox1->Text = sb->ToString();
form2->ShowDialog();
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Do you know where a good tutorial is for learning more on how strings work? String^ rank =strings[1] throws a System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled